# Not understanding Apple Doc

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to follow this how to document

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

However it is either out of date or when I created a new swift project I have noticed there is **NO**

> main.storyboard

or

> ViewController.swift

I have included what is setup from the get-go.

Is there a GIT of the project, or can someone please tell me do I have to create these files?

[image: default project setup]

Comment: because you are using a _SwiftUI_ template, rather than a _storyboard_ template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While creating the project in XCode 11, you will not get Storyboard by default.

With XCode 11 you get SwiftUI as default user interface.

You can select the User Interface to be Storyboard while creating the project

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When starting a new project in Xcode 11. You get the option to use either Storyboards or SwiftUI.

It looks like you have selected SwiftUI which does not use storyboards.

You might want to create the project again and select `Use Storyboards`